# Screen Lock from receiver

Tags: android

I am trying to Lock and unlock the screen,

The thing I am doing it as the following 
 A `Broadcast receiver` which checking whether the screen is ON of OFF,If the Screen is ON it will Lock the screen and if OFF it will unlock the screen.

The code I am using in the `Broadcast receiver` is

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        System.out.println("Entered Broadcaste Reciever........");
       context1 = context;
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            // DO WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO HERE
             mShaker = new ShakeListener(context);
                mShaker.setOnShakeListener(new ShakeListener.OnShakeListener () {
                  public void onShake()
                  {
                     PowerManager TempPowerManager = (PowerManager) context1.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                    PowerManager.WakeLock TempWakeLock = TempPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "TempWakeLock");
                    TempWakeLock.acquire();
                    final Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator)context1.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    vibe.vibrate(100);
            System.out.println("LISTENING SHAKE");
                  }
                });

        }
        else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            // AND DO WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO HERE

             mShaker = new ShakeListener(context);
                mShaker.setOnShakeListener(new ShakeListener.OnShakeListener () {
                  public void onShake()
                  {

                        mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)context1.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);



                    ComponentName mAdminName = new ComponentName(context1,LockActivity.class);
                    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON); 
                    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
                    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
                    context1.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
                    System.out.println("The Device  device admin enabled");
                    Intent  intent = new             Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
  intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mAdminName);
                                           intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,"onEnabled");
                                   mDPM.lockNow();
                                   mDPM.setMaximumTimeToLock(mAdminName,0);
                                   intent.putExtra("force-locked", DeviceAdminInfo.USES_POLICY_FORCE_LOCK);
   //                                           startActivityForResult(intent, 1); 
                  }
                });
        }
```

The problem is it is starting properly and upto 5 shakes its working properly and after that it is going infinite state and device get stucked..Somebody help me to find the solution

Comment: are you use onResume and onPause method in your code???

Answer (score 1):

Now, something to keep in mind, is that the order of events before the system screen turns off is:

> ExampleActivity.onPause() –> ScreenReceiver.onReceive()

Which is a little unintuitive as you’d think the receiver would get hit first – and so when you play around with setting booleans, etc, be aware of this little fact, and likewise when the screen turns on the order of events is:

> ExampleActivity.onResume() –> ScreenReceiver.onReceive()

```
 @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // when the screen is about to turn off
        if (ScreenReceiver.wasScreenOn) {
            // this is the case when onPause() is called by the system due to a screen state change
            System.out.println("SCREEN TURNED OFF");
        } else {
            // this is when onPause() is called when the screen state has not changed
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // only when screen turns on
        if (!ScreenReceiver.wasScreenOn) {
            // this is when onResume() is called due to a screen state change
            System.out.println("SCREEN TURNED ON");
        } else {
            // this is when onResume() is called when the screen state has not changed
        }
        super.onResume();
    }
```

[Reference from here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/)

Comment: there no errors reporting the problem is it will make the device slow during the execution.